# como verificar se uma imagem está online

Tags: javascript

Tenho que pegar uma image que pode estar em 2 diretórios e pra saber em qual diretório usar estou tentando usar a função a baixo.

O problema é que dentro do evento onError ou onLoad não consigo atribuir nenhum valor ao objeto imageTest.
Quero fazer esse teste sem usar ajax, somente usando javascript, mais to bem perdido no que fazer.

```
function is_img(file) {

        const imageTest = {
            status: false,
        };

        var img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = file;


        img.onload = () => {

            imageTest.status = true;
            console.log("A imagem " + file + " existe");
        }

        img.onerror = (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) => {

            imageTest.status = false;
            console.log("A imagem " + file + " não existe");

        }

        if (imageTest.status === true) {

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Porque vc não verifica em backend a origem do arquivo, fazendo uma requisição ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma imagem, assim como outros recursos Web (audio, video, etc) são carregados via uma requisição. Para verificar se existem, ou se estão disponíveis, pode fazer um request para a *url* do recurso e testar se retorna sem erros, assim:

```
function is_img(file) {
    var imagemRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    imagemRequest .open('HEAD', file, false);
    imagemRequest .send();

    var resultado = imagemRequest.status;

    if (resultado == 404)
       imageTest.status = false

    // testar outros códigos, como 500 e 503 por exemplo..
}
```

Comment: bem notado, removi, a ideia era mostrar só o `if`obrigado ;)

Comment: sempre recebo esse aviso e a imagem não carrega::
from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso deve funcionar:

```
  function isImg(file, result) {

            var img = document.createElement('img'); 
            img.src = file;
            img.onload = () => {
                result.action(true)
            }

            img.onerror = () => {
              result.action(false)
            }
        }

var file = 'teste.jpg', 
    call = {
        action:function(status) {
            if (status) {
                console.log("A imagem " + file + " existe")
            } else {
                console.log("A imagem " + file + " não existe")
            } 
    }}
    isImg(file, call);
```

Também pode fazer assim:

```
function isImg(src, call1, call2) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = call1; 
    img.onerror = call2;
    img.src = src;
}

var img = 'teste.jpg', 
isImg(img, function(status) {
   if (status) {
       console.log("A imagem " + file + " existe")
    } 
}, function(status) {
   if(status) {
      console.log("A imagem " + file + " não existe")
   } 
});
```